# Automatic birthday email send out of MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I created a table named `Customers` with the following columns:

1. `ID`
2. `Name`
3. `Birthdate`
4. `Email`
5. `Manager`

**Entries**

```
Name  Birthdate   Email           Manager
----  ----------  --------------  -------
Jan   1986-05-15  jan@gmail.com   None
Koos  1986-07-24  Koos@gmail.com  1
Sam   1991-07-24  Sam@gmail.com   1
```

Meaning that Koos and Sam's manager is Jan.

Now what I want to do is to determine if someone has a birthday today.

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[EmailData]

AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
Declare @Date date

SELECT GETDATE(), Month(GetDate()), Day(GetDate()), Year(GetDate())

select
       a.ID, a.Name,      
        a.BirthDate as EmpBirthday,
    b.Name as Manager, 
        b.Email as ManEmail
    from dbo.Customers  a
        inner join dbo.Customers b
        on a.Manager = b.ID
where Month(a.BirthDate) = Month(GetDate())
    and Day(a.BirthDate) = Day(GetDate())

END
Go
```

The above works fine, I get the results I want 100%.

What I want to do now is send the email of each employee whose birthday it is today to the employee's manager.

I came up with this but it does not seem to work and I have no idea why:

```
Create PROCEDURE EmailData

AS
BEGIN

Declare @email             nvarchar(128)
Declare @Date              date

SELECT GETDATE(), Month(GetDate()), Day(GetDate()), Year(GetDate())

DECLARE rcpt_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select 
       b.Email
       from dbo.Customers  a
       inner join dbo.Customers b
       on a.Manager = b.ID
where Month(a.BirthDate) = Month(GetDate())
      and Day(a.BirthDate) = Day(GetDate())

OPEN rcpt_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM rcpt_cursor INTO @email

DECLARE @ServerAddr nvarchar(128)
Set @ServerAddr = 'smtp.gmail.com'

DECLARE @From nvarchar(128)
Set @From = 'My Email Address'

DECLARE @Bodytext nvarchar(512)
Set @BodyText = 'Your Employees have a birthday today.'

DECLARE @User nvarchar(128)
Set @User = 'My Email Address'

DECLARE @Password nvarchar(128)
Set @Password = 'My Password'

DECLARE @SSL int
Set @SSL = 0

DECLARE @Port int
Set @Port = 587

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
PRINT @email
DECLARE @subject nvarchar(255)
SELECT @Subject = 'Happy Birthday' +  @email
EXEC EmailData @ServerAddr, 
    @from, @email, @subject, @BodyText, @User, @Password, @SSL, @Port
FETCH NEXT FROM rcpt_cursor
INTO @email
END
CLOSE rcpt_cursor
DEALLOCATE rcpt_cursor

End
Go
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: So where "Manager" is NULL the following rows with 1 are the employees of that person? Sounds like a bad design to me, SQL SERVER ordering is arbitrary, you need to use nested sets, that way this could have been alot easier to implement without a cursor/loop.

Comment: No I have a No Reporting line so if someone don't have a reporting line they report to No reporting line. Meaning if No Reporting line was entry Number 4 the manager will be 4.

Comment: What is the error? What do you see in the proffiler?

Comment: If I ran it exactly as on top. I get "Command(s) completed successfully." But nothing happens I don't receive the email. So that is why I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: What does _"does not seem to work"_ mean? An error? What is it? Incorrect results? What are the current results? What are you expecting?

Comment: I am expecting to get an email but nothing is happening. I get the results like the emails that have to receive a email. But it does not send a email and I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I cracked it

First of all I set up a Database mail account

Then I wrote a procedure

```
USE [Customers]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_SendEmail]

AS

Declare @email        nvarchar(128)
Declare @name         nvarchar(128)
Declare @Date         date

SELECT GETDATE(), Month(GetDate()), Day(GetDate()), Year(GetDate())

DECLARE rcpt_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select
       a.Name,
       b.Email 
    from dbo.Customers  a
        inner join dbo.Customers b
        on a.Manager = b.ID
where Month(a.BirthDate) = Month(GetDate())
    and Day(a.BirthDate) = Day(GetDate())

OPEN rcpt_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM rcpt_cursor


INTO @name,@email

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
PRINT @email
Declare @subject nvarchar(255)
Declare @Bodytext nvarchar(512)

Set @BodyText = @Name + '' + ' has a birthday today. Please congrad him'
Set @Subject = 'Employee Birthday' 

exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@Profile_Name = 'HappyBirthday',
@Recipients = @email,
@Body = @BodyText,
@Subject = @Subject

FETCH NEXT FROM rcpt_cursor
INTO @name,@email


END 

CLOSE rcpt_cursor

DEALLOCATE rcpt_cursor

Go 

Exec [usp_SendEmail]
```

The procedure now run through the hole customer table check if there are birthday dates that much and send the email to the managers whose employees have a birthday.